# Wordpress: How to administrate Background-Image and Content Slide

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am about to build a Wordpress theme for a non-blog website. I am familiar with the basic post/page concept and I used to set a static page being the front page.

Now I want the fron-page **to change** **its background image** and a little **part of its content** every few seconds ([Here](http://demo.wpbakery.com/?theme=architectos) is an example of what I am trying to achieve.)

I already know how to develop the javascript and HTML part of that! **I would like to know how to make those changeable items (background-image as well as the small content) to be managable in the Wordpress admin area** (Since that's the whole point o a cms, right :-)).

How would you do that? Is there a plugin to connect custom contents like that? Or do I have to build my own plugin? I would appreciate your thoughts :-)

Comment: I won't give an answer the question is too vague - it's more a tutorial question. You should set them up as Custom Post Types, set the background up as a Featured Image/Custom Field and pull those titles, content and imagery in with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The rough steps to take:

1. Create a custom [posttype](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_post_type)
2. In the `supports` option enable `thumbnail`
3. Create a few posts with a featured image (and other data you want)
4. Fetch your posts using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
5. Loop your posts.
6. Do JS magic.

questions? ask.